# Seeing calls to analytics.tiktok.com in our DNN site

Tags: dotnetnuke, tiktok

We have a DNN site and I noticed on our home page that the dev tools show an error with an events.js file that is trying to call "analytics.tiktok.com". It is being blocked. I don't know if this is purposeful and I've searched our DNN modules code but haven't found an such reference.

The other devs can confirm they haven't added such code. I've searched the code folders for a file named events.js but haven't found one. I'm aware that DNN has large portions of it that are data driven but I don't know what tables to query to see if there's code that has that URL.

Is anyone aware if DNN or kendo controls has an references to tiktok?

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely not part of DNN.

Another place to look for these calls are the skin (theme) controls in use, or the default.aspx. Anyway, if no one is aware of this stuff, I would check if you have a security hole (old Telerik libraries, unsafe passwords in FTP accounts...)

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at the location in which that is embedded into the source of your webpage. Depending on where it is, that might help you track down "where" it is coming from.

It could be coming from inside source for a module, in the content of a module, in module settings, in a container, in a skin/theme, etc.